# Trouble installing any plugins for vim (using pathogen)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, pathogen

I have searched all over the internet and have not been able to find any resources which will ELI5 vim plugins. I found a resource that said that pathogen makes it simple so I got that. It is in my `~/.vim` directory.  I have also added the two lines:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()
```

The plugin I am most intent on installing is delimitMate.vim though I am also working with supertab.vim. I have cloned each plugin's git repository into its own directory in `~/.vim/bundle`.

That's pretty much everything I've done. I'm sure there's something I'm missing but everything I can find seems to say that the plugins should now magically work. I've tried the command, `git submodule init && git submodule update` though I found only one resource which suggested this command and it gave no annotation as to what it is doing (a.k.a. I'm not sure what it's supposed to do).

Thank you for all help and suggestions!

I am running linux Mint btw.

Comment: What is the exact directory pathogen is in? It should be in `~/.vim/autoload/`

Answer (score 1):

The `pathogen.vim` file must be in `~/.vim/autoload/`:

```
~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Yes, Pathogen makes installing/removing plugins easier but you can't really expect anything to work "magically" if you don't pay a minimum of attention:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle; \
curl -Sso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
    https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Did you notice the `/autoload` part?

For your defense, Tim Pope's plugins are generally awesome but they are often lacking in the documentation department. The installation instruction above assumes quite a lot and doesn't explain much.